# Does nginx try_files have a bug

Tags: nginx

I have a directory structure like this:

```
/opt/mysite/www:
F: index.html
D: connect/
F: -- index.html
F: -- page.html
```

With URL http://www.mysite.io/connect, the try_files results in a 301 to:
http://www.mysite.io:8080/connect/

Why is nginx appending the listen port?

```
server {
listen       8080;
server_name  www.mysite.io;
index index.htm index.html /index.htm;
root /opt/mysite/www/;
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is not caused by `try_files`. You have something else going on. What is running on port 80?

Comment: Azure -> port mapping external 80 -> server 8080

Comment: The trouble is in your application, then.

Comment: Thanks for the thought trigger. I remembered I have another server in a separate file that has a regex match on *.mysite.io and it was taking over.  Curious the try_files wasn't looping and getting a match though, interesting evaluation path.

Comment: It was definintely hitting the above server, I did a dummy add_header that was being returned in the 301.